# Compatibility issue with Intel DP43TF and Promise Fastrek TX4650

Tags: motherboard, raid, compatibility

When I installed a Promise Fastrek TX4650 PCI-E RAID card to an [Intel DP43TF motherboard](http://ark.intel.com/products/36461/Intel-Desktop-Board-DP43TF), the RAID card does not function (totally). But when I put the same RAID card to another motherboard, the RAID card works as expected.

Any clue?